# can't ssh to virtualbox centos from my ubuntu terminal

Tags: centos, ssh, virtualbox

I'm new to linux and I want to connect from my terminal to centos that I installed in virtualbox but it take too long and I have to stop it
what should I do?

Comment: what sort of networking did you setup for the virt?

Answer (score 2):

Two very important things:

1) Make sure that you have the OpenSSH server installed
2) On your VirtualBox VM, make sure that your NIC is in 'bridged' mode or whatever terminology that VirtualBox uses so that your VM has an IP address on your local network

Comment: I did this things

Answer (score 1):

Could be tuns of things in here.

Check communication between machines.

```
From Ubuntu ping CentOS IP
$ ping xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

Check if SSH is installed

```
In CentOS
$ sudo rpm -q openssh
```

Check your firewall, see if SSH connections are accepted (port 22).

```
In CentOS
$ sudo iptables -L
```

Check if ssh service is running

```
In CentOS
$ sudo service sshd status
```

Check port listening (default 22)

```
IN CentOS
$ sudo netstat -tulpn
```

If all of this are correct, troubleshoot with logs. See in real time what happens when "sshing" to the server.

```
IN CentOS
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/secure
```

look for your user and|or IP address.

SSH with verbose mode in order to see where is getting stuck.

```
IN Ubuntu
$ ssh -vvv user@ipaddress
```

Comment: ping running correctly

Comment: service running

Comment: it's work now but after 1 min why take so long?

Comment: thank you your answer but I don;t understand some of them because I'm newbie